# jq - extract nested objects into CSV

Tags: csv, nested, jq

I would like to flatten the following (elasticsearch result, simplified) into a CSV file with repeating parent values.

The aggregation has three levels that I would like to flatten, site name, account id, user names, and counted. The renaming of the CSV headers, as shown, would be nice.

I tried with map_values() but the nested structure gives me a hard time.

### Input File Content

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "by_site_group_and_account_and_user_name": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 4880,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 760270,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "S1",
          "doc_count": 335216,
          "by_account_Id": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 429,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 34655,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": 1396220,
                "doc_count": 277532,
                "by_user_name": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 2580,
                  "buckets": [
                    {
                      "key": "S1_U1",
                      "doc_count": 244602
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "S1_U2",
                      "doc_count": 30350
                    }
                  ]}},
              {
                "key": 14770032,
                "doc_count": 23029,
                "by_user_name": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                    {
                      "key": "S1_U3",
                      "doc_count": 23016
                    }
                  ]}}]}},
        {
          "key": "S2",
          "doc_count": 146453,
          "by_account_Id": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 2380,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 108259,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": 14733289,
                "doc_count": 20138,
                "by_user_name": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 2406,
                  "buckets": [
                    {
                      "key": "S2_U1",
                      "doc_count": 13247
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "S2_U2",
                      "doc_count": 4485
                    }
                  ]}},
              {
                "key": 14769976,
                "doc_count": 18056,
                "by_user_name": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                    {
                      "key": "S2_U3",
                      "doc_count": 17015
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "S2_U4",
                      "doc_count": 1041
                    }
                  ]}}]}}]}}}
```

### Desired Output

```
"Site", "Account", "User", "Counted"
"S1", 1396220, "S1_U1", 244602 
"S1", 1396220, "S1_U2", 30350
"S1", 14770032, "S1_U3", 23016
"S2", 14733289, "S2_U1", 13247
"S2", 14733289, "S2_U2", 4485
"S2", 14769976, "S2_U3", 17015
"S2", 14769976, "S2_U4", 1041
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Just collect the items into an array using `+` and use parentheses to retain the context kevel. [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1GsoKSqzvw)

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty simple combination of grabbing some information, then looping over descendants.

```
(
   [ "Site", "Account", "User", "Counted" ],
   (
      .aggregations.by_site_group_and_account_and_user_name.buckets[] |
      .key as $site |
      .by_account_Id.buckets[] |
      .key as $account |
      .by_user_name.buckets[] |
      [ $site, $account, .key, .doc_count ]
   )
) | @csv
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7aFy19f4CQ) on jqplay